# Simple Push Menu in CSS3 and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to add a push menu in my website. This menu has to slide out from left and should overlap the current page. I'm using the following code but it's not working. Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong?

CSS:

```
    #menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -240px ;
      position: fixed;

  width: 240px;
      height: 100%;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  margin: 0;

  list-style: none;
  background: #333;
  z-index: 9999;

      transition: all 0.3s ease;
      -webkit-transition all 0.3s ease;
  }

  #menu a {
        display: block;
       color: #fff;
        padding: 15px 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.05 );
    }

  .animate {
          transform: translateX(240px);
         -webkit-transform: translateX(240px);
     }
```

JavaScipt:

```
            $(function() {
                  $('#toggle-menu').click(function() {
                           toggleMenu();
                    });
             })(jQuery);



         function toggleMenu() {
                if ($('#menu').hasClass('animate')) {
                    $('#menu').removeClass('animate');
                               }
                 else {
                       $('#menu').addClass('animate');
                      }

                 //$('#menu').toggleClass('animate');
             }
```

HTML:

```
      <div id="menu">
            <ul>
             <li><a href="#"> Home </a></li>
               <li><a href="#"> Home </a></li>
              <li><a href="#"> Home </a></li>
               </ul>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code:

- There's missing the `#toggle-menu` element
- You're setting `display:none` in the `#menu` style
- jQuery sintax adding the `.click()` event

Your code fixed, and a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bL62bek2/) (http://jsfiddle.net/bL62bek2/)

```js
$('#toogle-menu').click(function() {
   toggleMenu();
});

$('#menu').click(function() {
   toggleMenu();
});

function toggleMenu() {
   if ($('#menu').hasClass('animate')) {
      $('#menu').removeClass('animate');
   } else {
      $('#menu').addClass('animate');
   }
   //$('#menu').toggleClass('animate');
}
```

```css
#toogle-menu{
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:30px;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color:#333;
    color:#fff;
}
#menu {
  /*display: none;*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -240px ;
  position: fixed;

  width: 240px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  margin: 0;

  list-style: none;
  background: #333;
  z-index: 9999;

  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition all 0.3s ease;
  }

#menu a {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.05 );
}

.animate {
    transform: translateX(240px);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(240px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="toogle-menu">menu</div>
<div id="menu" class="animate">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#"> Home </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Home </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Home </a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

created a working example for you. Hope it helps!

```js
$(".menu").click(function() {
  $('#menu').toggleClass('animate');
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#menu {
  top: 50px;
  transform: translateX(-300px);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-300px);
  position: fixed;
  width: 240px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background: #333;
  z-index: 9999;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition all 0.3s ease;
}
#menu a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
}
#menu.animate {
  transform: translateX(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"> Home </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"> Home </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"> Home </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="menu">click</div>
```